# Hide/unhide specific objects in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have a macro to hide/unhide callouts.

The intention is to have an information button that once presses show or hide the information callouts.

The problem is that I have other arrows and shapes that I don't want to be hidden.

With the following code (1) I can hide all objects:

```
Dim sObject As Shape
For Each sObject In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If sObject.Visible = False Then
        sObject.Visible = True
    Else
        sObject.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

And with this code (2) I can hide/unhide specific callout shapes

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangular Callout 6").Visible = False Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangular Callout 6").Visible = True
Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangular Callout 6").Visible = False
End If
```

How can I have the first code (1) to run through the callout shapes only like in the second code (2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Dim sObject As Shape
For Each sObject In ActiveSheet.Shapes
   If Not InStr(sObject.Name, "Callout") = 0 Then sObject.Visible = Not sObject.Visible
Next sObject
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Mahai, but the if not line appears as an error 'If Not InStr(sObject .Name, "Callout") = 0 Then'

Comment: Edited, should be ok now

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the visible property is a boolean, you can shorten your code :

```
Sub InvertAllShapesVisibility(wS As Worksheet)
    Dim sObject As Shape
    '''Invert visibility of all shapes
    For Each sObject In wS.Shapes
        sObject.Visible = Not sObject.Visible
    Next sObject
End Sub
```

How to use it :

```
Sub Test1_Selrac()
    InvertAllShapesVisibility ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

---

And for a single shape :

```
Sub RevertShapeVisibility(wS As Worksheet, ShapeName As String)
    Dim sObject As Shape
    '''Invert visibility of all shapes containing the KeyWord
    For Each sObject In wS.Shapes
        If sObject.Name = ShapeName Then sObject.Visible = Not sObject.Visible
    Next sObject
End Sub
```

How to use it :

```
Sub Test2_Selrac()
    RevertShapeVisibility ActiveSheet, "Rectangular Callout 6"
End Sub
```

---

And for multiple shapes containing keywords :

```
Sub RevertCalloutsVisibility(wS As Worksheet, KeyWord As String)
    Dim sObject As Shape
    '''Invert visibility of one shape
    For Each sObject In wS.Shapes
        If Instr(1,sObject.Name,KeyWord) Then sObject.Visible = Not sObject.Visible
    Next sObject
End Sub
```

How to use it :

```
Sub Test3_Selrac()
    RevertCalloutsVisibility ActiveSheet, "Rectangular Callout"
End Sub
```

Comment: R3uK, thanks, but I need only the 'Rectangular Callout' shapes to be hidden/unhidden

Comment: @Selrac : See `Test3`! ;)

Comment: Thanks R2uK. That is what I was looking for. You are very good.

Comment: @Selrac : Glad I could help! ;)